# Acessar matriz dentro de função

Tags: php

Boa Tarde,

Estou montando uma batalha naval e estou com a seguinte dificuldade:
Não estou conseguindo acessar uma determinada matriz criada dentro de uma função. Dentro da mesma função eu chamo outra função que acessa essa matriz, porém o PHP informa que não está definido essa matriz. Abaixo a estrutura que estou fazendo.

```html
//SORTEIA OS NAVIOS
 function reiniciar(){
  $navios = array();

  //ZERA A MATRIZ
  for ($l=-1; $l < 31; $l++) { 
   for ($c=-1; $c < 31 ; $c++) { 
    $navios[$l][$c] = -1;
   } 
  }

  //CHAMA AS FUNÇÕES
  sorteia(3,5,"P");//CONSTROI OS PORTA AVIÕES
    }

    function sorteia($quantidade,$n_posicoes,$embarcacao){
        if($navios[$rand_linha][$rand_coluna] == -1){
          //AQUI DIZ QUE $navios ESTA INDEFINIDO
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mas no seu código o $navios esta mesmo indefinido.. Onde você esta passando $navios para function sorteia? E onde ela recebe?

Comment: não entendi a ideia da necessidade disso, como deveria fazer?

Comment: teria que passar $navios como um tipo de referencia para a função sorteia?

Comment: a necessidade é que se você não passar $navios para a function sorteia ele não funciona. Veja bem, você esta setando $navios na function reiniciar, mas você não passa $navios para function sorteia, nem chama a function reiniciar lá. Portanto ele aparece indefinido porque tecnicamente você esta fazendo um IF em uma variável que não existe naquela parte do código. Entendeu?

Comment: Pode passar direto se quiser: sorteia(3,5,"P", $navios); e acresenta no recebimento function sorteia($quantidade,$n_posicoes,$embarcacao, $navios)

Answer (score 0):

Bom não sei se consegui explicar direito pelos comentários então vamos lá.

O que acontece no teu código é o seguinte, você está utilizando `functions` correto? Então a variavel que você criou na `function reiniciar` so pode ser utilizada la! A não ser que você a declare como global, então na `function sorteia` você  recebe 3 variaveis:

```
 function sorteia($quantidade,$n_posicoes,$embarcacao)
```

Você pode então trabalhar com estas 3 variáveis aqui porque você está setando seus valores quando faz a chamada do método:

```
sorteia(3,5,"P");
```

Porem `$navios` que é a variavel que você usa no `if`, não existe aqui porque você não passou e/ou não setou um valor para ela. No caso você poderia passar diretamente:

```
sorteia(3,5,"P", $navios);
```

E depois recebe-la na `function`:

```
function sorteia($quantidade,$n_posicoes,$embarcacao, $navios)
```

Assim você poderia trabalhar com ela na `function` sorteia.

Espero que tenha conseguido explicar, qualquer dúvida pergunte

Comment: Entendi, fiz isso e deu certo, porém preciso exibir ele fora dessa function sorteia, pois chamarei a função sorteia várias vezes para ir alimentando esse array. E pelo que percebi seu eu colocar dentro da function sorteia a exibição em tela do array ele exibe, porém quando coloco fora ele não aparece nada do que eu inseri.

Answer (score 0):

Isso que estou fazendo:

```html
        //CHAMA AS FUNÇÕES
  sorteia(3,5,"P",$navios);//CONSTROI OS PORTA AVIÕES
  //sorteia(5,3,"D",$navios);//CONSTROI OS DESTROIER
  //sorteia(7,2,"S",$navios);//CONSTROI OS SUBMARINOS
  //sorteia(10,1,"B",$navios);//CONSTROI OS BOTES
  
  echo "<table border='1'";
   for ($l=0; $l < 30 ; $l++) { 
    echo "<tr>";
     for ($c=0; $c < 30 ; $c++) { 
      echo "<td>";
       echo 
      echo "</td>";
     }
    echo "</tr>";
   }
  echo "</table>";
```